# Docker image on GCP: Where to copy files required by Python script

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile

I have a Python script that requires OpenCV's haarcascade.xml file to make a facial recognition. I successfully built and pushed Docker image on Kubernetes (Google Cloud Platform) with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7

ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y sudo && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


RUN sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y apt-utils build-essential cmake && sudo apt-get install -y libgtk-3-dev && sudo apt-get install -y libboost-all-dev && sudo apt-get install -y default-libmysqlclient-dev

RUN pip install setuptools mysqlclient cmake Flask gunicorn pybase64 google-cloud-vision google-cloud-storage protobuf nltk fuzzywuzzy PyPDF2 numpy python-csv google-cloud-language pandas SQLAlchemy PyMySQL pytz Unidecode torch tensorflow==1.15 transformers imutils scikit-learn scikit-image scipy==1.4.1 opencv-python text2num sklearn
RUN pip install dlib

COPY app.py ./app.py
COPY haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml ./haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml

CMD ["python", "./app.py"]
```

In the Python notebook I have haarcascade.xml file without a path:

```
def face_recog(image):
    face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
    img = cv2.imread(image)
```

The pod runs smoothly, no errors, no restarts, but this part of code is not working due to the "missing" haarcascade file.

I know I have two options:

1. Put the full path of haarcascade in the notebook (which I don't know given is a Docker image)
2. Fix the COPY haarcascade.xml file in Dockerfile so that Python script finds it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: did you connect to the pod to see where the `haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml` is?

Comment: No, I just accessed the logs with `kubectl logs <pod_name>`. How do I do that ?

Comment: You mean by using ssh in the instance ?

Comment: Hi, You can use `kubectl exec -ti <podname> bash` to connect to container for debugging purposes. This works on most images right away. More info [here](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/pages/container_debugging/executing_a_command_in_a_container.html).